# send_mail() doesn't work on page reload

Tags: django, email, django-views

I'm discovering Django, and I don't understand why send_mail() function in my index view is working fine one time but not when I reload the index page.

view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
model = Quote
template_name = 'quotes/index.html'
context_object_name = 'quotes_list'

send_mail('Test Dj', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
['to@example'], fail_silently=False)


def get_queryset(self):
    return Quote.objects.all()
```

First time I load the page, everything working, I get a mail.

Then I reload the page, and I don't get a second mail.

Comment: Have idea only about caching in your browser and sending to 'spam' catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the placement of the `send_mail()` call which is inside the class definition.  Django will often lazy-load objects, meaning that the code will only be imported when it is first used.  In your case, when you first execute the view, Django imports the module containing your view, and, while parsing the `IndexView` class, sends out an email.  However, on subsequent page views, the code has already been loaded, the class definition is not reparsed and so the `send_mail()` call is never made.

You have to move the `send_mail()` call inside a view function within your `IndexView` class.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    ....
    def get(self, request):
        # Send email on every get request.
        send_mail('Test Dj', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example'], fail_silently=False)
        return super(IndexView, self).get(request)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a final, can you explain the super(IndexView,self).get(request) and not simple "return request" ?

Comment: @user777466 The super call invokes the `get` method of the base class (generic.ListView) to continue processing the GET request as per normal. ie It will continue processing the request for your list view and return a HttpResponse with the list contents.